# Can give some one credit for an action you think is negative?

Tags: meaning, expressions

Normally "To Give Credit" in the expression "Give credit where credit is due." relates to someone acknowledging another's persons positive actions. (ie: Give him credit, through hard work he was able doubled his grade point average).

Is it possible to use it to acknowledge another persons negative actions, or could you use it derogatorily? (ie: "You got to give them credit, they were the one who laid out the plan for the heist." Or "You have to give him credit, they fell for 6 email scams in the last year alone")

Would I be able to retort/respond to a persons statement.

```
Person A: "He gave thousands of dollars to an orphanage." 
Person B: "You got to give credit where credit is due, he was only able to do this by stealing it all from the elderly."
```

Comment: Although your examples are poor, with singulars and plurals mixed up, **credit** can be used negatively , without **give**, in the sense of **believe**. **You will hardly credit his stupidity/laziness etc**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We generally only use the word "credit" to apply to positive things. If someone is responsible for something negative, we use a different word, like "blame".

I recall a few years ago the media did a self-appraisal about their use of the word "credit" when applied to terrorist attacks. That is, they would say, "There was a terrorist attack in Boston that killed 9 people. Group X has claimed credit for the attack." They decided that it was inappropriate to use "credit" in this context and switched to saying "claimed responsibility".

Of course whether something is positive or negative is sometimes a matter of opinion. Like whether you say that "Senator Manchin deserves credit for blocking the Build Back Better bill from passing" or "Senator Manchin deserves the blame for blocking the Build Back Better bill" depends on whether you think the bill in question was a good thing or a bad thing.

You could use the word ironically. Like, "Oh, so Bob deserves the CREDIT for fouling up this big order and making us all work overtime to fix it."

But otherwise, you should generally use a negative word, like "blame", to describe someone causing something bad. Or a neutral word, like "responsibility", if you don't want to express a judgement.

Answer (score 1):

When you use "credit where credit is due" this way it's ironic. In your example Person B is crediting someone for being a first rate con artist.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only 'give credit' for something positive (unless you are being sarcastic). Your suggested example would only work the other way round.

> He stole thousands of pounds from the elderly, but, to give him credit, he did give a lot of it to an orphanage.